# bash function that accepts arguments and returns array to variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to figure if this is a syntax or logic problem with bash.

It you can return a value from a function and assign it to a variable like;

```
var=$(the_function)
```

I am trying to add multiple arguments to the function call that include variables, paren `()`, double colon `::`, along with both single and double quotes with no luck.

an example of what i am trying is the following;

```
var=$(db_query "SELECT nextval('the_seq'::regclass) FROM the_table;" "$dbname")
```

the function successfully queries the database when not trying to return the value.

I keep getting an "unexpected `)'" for the very last `)` that wraps the entire function.  I have tried numerous forms of quoting and escaping but take away `var=$` along with the wrapping ( ) and the function works as intended.

Would this be my incorrect logic, syntax or both?

Comment: [Show us the line that fails.](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var="$(the_function parm1 parm2)"
```

or:

```
var="`the_function parm1 parm2`"
```